# What is the etymology of the Baseball term “meat hand”?

Tags: etymology, idioms

The term is used to signify the non gloved hand of the pitcher.  I've only ever heard it used relative to the pitcher.

For example, *“On the bunt the pitcher used his meat hand instead of gloving the ball to get the out at first.”*

For a third baseman someone would just say that he *“palmed the ball to get the out”.*

So it's obvious what the term means, but is there any way to understand how that originated?  First use, what (or who) made it popular - etc.  And perhaps why it only applies to a pitcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not restricted to pitchers; every player has a meat hand and a glove hand, and my impression is that it's used most often of catchers.

The earliest use I've found is from 1911, in a short story by Charles Van Loan, “The Crab” in *The Big League*, 1911, where a first baseman praises his colleague:

> “There ain’t a third baseman in the country who has anything on him when it comes to handling a bunt or a slow ball. He comes gallopin’ in on ’em, drops his glove to the ground, straightens up, and *wham!* I can shut my eyes and take a throw from him, because I know just where he’s going to put it—and it’ll never be on the ‘meat-hand’ side, either.”

That is, the throw always comes to the first-baseman's glove; he doesn’t have to reach across his body.

Hugh S. Fullerton defines the term in “The Baseball Primer”, *The American Magazine*, LXXIV (May-Nov 1912), p. 204:

> **Meat Hand**—The throwing hand of a player, the term resulting from the fact that the throwing hand is bare while the other is protected by a glove or mitt.

But there is nothing in these to tell us whether the term was invented by a player or a writer.